# QNEAT3 Iso-Area as Contours interpolation problem

Tags: qgis, interpolation, network-analyst

I have a network of roads in district, and i want to make Iso-Area as Contours from Layer of points (schools). So, I have some problems with it. Firstly, I don't understand why these jagged contours appear and how to remove them
[image]

And also i have a problem with centers of contours.
[image]

school point should be in the center of first contour. Please, say how to fix these problems?